# Insert records into two tables c# console application

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I implemented the c# console application to retrieve data from SAP system. Firstly I retrieve invoice header from SAP system and insert into database. Secondly, I retrieve invoice detail item from SAP system and insert into database. They are parent child relation ship. The problem is sometimes header record failed to insert and sometimes invoice detail item failed to insert. Is there anyway to solve the issue? Should I use transactions? If yes, where should in use transactions, in SQL or in c# ? Is there a way to insert both header and item records at once?

Comment: Can you please show us your code? What is the error you get?
Please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or [How to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to insert both header and item records at once?

Yes: transactions; what you're asking for is atomicity, which is the "A" in [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)

> Should I use transactions?

Yes, if that is what you're trying to achieve (other approaches are possible too, for example eventual consistency without transactions)

> If yes, where should in use transactions, in SQL or in c# ?

Yes; either are valid and viable; the choice is largely subjective and down to context.